# Binding database data to a dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, drop-down-menu

I have been trying for a long time to fix the bugs I'm encountering with my dropdownlists in my project. I'm getting data this with at the moment and it's working fine:

```
 using (InfoEntities ie = new InfoEntities())
        {
            var sqlddl = (from query in ie.Table_Customers
                          from q in ie.Accounting_PriceType
                          where query.TypeID == 1 && q.ID == 1
                          orderby query.Customers
                          select query).Distinct().ToList();
            DropDownListCust.DataTextField = "Customers";
            DropDownListCust.DataValueField = "ID";
            DropDownListCust.DataSource = sqlddl;
            DropDownListCust.DataBind();
        }
```

Now when the user saves the data and opens the website again I need the saved value that was chosen on the dropdownlist earlier retreived. This also works fine but the problem is I'm getting duplicates. Anyways I'm doing it like this and I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong:

On the page load i load my dropdownlist to get all the items plus the following to get the saved value:

```
 DropDownListCust.SelectedItem.Text = sql.Customers;
```

This makes my DDL very buggy, some items dissapear and also sometimes dupicated values. Can anyone please help? I'm using LINQ but I can use some other methods as long as it's fixed.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem like this:

```
DropDownList1.ClearSelection();
DropDownList1.Items.FindByText(sql.Customer).Selected = true;
```